# PIN enforcement with MDM solution

Tags: lock-screens, wpa2

I have a technical question to the android os. A phone doesn't have to have some PIN or other unlocking options but what exactly happens when you take this phone into a MDM solution such as MobileIron? It gives you some policies and somehow you are forced to take a PIN. Is this because of the policy or because of the android OS which says: "oh you want to use certificates, well I do not allow you to use them without a PIN". the phone uses wpa2-enterprise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MDM solution can require that you set a PIN.

The [Google Apps Device Policy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.enterprise.dmagent) app, for example, can require you to set a PIN. This is described in the [Google Device Policy for Android](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/190930?hl=en) if you want more details.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume that the operating system will not enforce a PIN just because a certificate is used, right?